# Edit removed during grace period

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

What's does this mean? `[edit removed during grace period]`?

As usual I was reviewing pending reviews and the following revision was listed under [reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5234512), but I didn't understand the meaning behind that sentence.

I went to the question and I saw no edits whatsoever, the only line I could see is the one I mentioned above as the edit reason and in the description it states

*No changes to display.*

---

Relevant Screen

[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After an edit, there is a 5-minute “grace period” during which all edits to the same post by the same user are silently conflated. See the [FAQ entry on editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work/21789#21789) for more information.

If a user submits an edit, and within 5 minutes submits another edit that returns the post to its original state, then there are two consecutive revisions of the post that have the same content. The revision is still shown in the history, with the message “[edit removed during grace period]”.

A null edit like this has all the usual effects of an edit, including bumping the post, throwing it into the reopen queue if it was closed and met the [other qualifying conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078), allowing voters to change their vote, etc.

Answer (score 27):

Ok I got what does this mean, say if a user edits a post, for example he removes a word called

```
testing
```

and than again, he adds it back, than system automatically uses `[edit removed during grace period]` as a reason to show that the edit was again changed to the original post during the grace period, hence no real edit was made.

I tried a demo on one of my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24197876/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

After you make an edit there is grace period to stop people from spamming edits so they can get the 'edit * posts' badges.

Comment: It's also useful if the OP has included things like their database password inside the code - they have five minutes to remove them before the original post shows up in the revision history.