# Why are new tags not deleted in the grace period?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, asking-questions, tag-wiki

I read [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251221/2932052) and its [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251222/2932052) and as I tried out the auto-vivification of tags beyond 1,5 rep, I found no traces of this edit due to the grace period rule for edits, this question and answers are dedicated to: [Edit removed during grace period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262810/2932052)

BTW: my [test tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/on-the-fly-tagging) survived and attracts questions until 03:00 UTC ;-)

Do you share my impression that this is inconsistent? And - because everything inconsistent on SO has a reason: **Why are on-the-fly-tags not included in the grace period magic?**

Answer (score 5):

Because the system does not check to see if the tag has zero questions when you retag a post. There is no possible way to determine, when editing, that the tag you're removing was created on-the-fly and is being removed during the grace period. All it looks at is that you're removing the tag. For all it knows, the tag could have been applied to another question already during that grace period.

Once the tag has been created, it must wait until the next time the system burns all the empty tags.

Comment: I understand, because tags are a very non-local entity, so it's harder to apply a (smaller) grace period to them.